# How to migrate a tiny Silex application to Symfony 4 with as low effort as possible?

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I have a couple backends written as single-file Silex applications - basically the example from https://silex.symfony.com/ just with a couple more routes. No classes, no frills.

Is there any way to replicate this tiny low effort structure in Symfony 4 or do I really have to blow each backend up to the full Symfony structure in the Symfony way?

Comment: It's a chicken and egg thing.  Someone with a good understanding of how the framework works can strip it down and probably port a silex app with a minimum of effort while keeping it mostly as is.  But gaining that experience and expertise will probably take longer than just rewriting the apps the "Symfony" way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [the Symfony 4 MicroKernelTrait](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/micro_kernel_trait.html). This is going to be very similar to the single-file-app Silex model.

It is a bit more verbose than Silex but it will allow you to migrate up easily if you decide you need more of the framework.